# Ipsec: How to forward certains IPs to use VPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I connected to a VPN using Strongswan IPsec in Ubuntu.

Im trying to telnet to an IP address but is giving time out due that it would need to be done through the VPN.

How can I "only requests to these IPs address to use the VPN and the rest use the normal internet" ?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody's answering, I'll tell you that:

- though this approach is technically possible, you're overcomplicating things. This will make it very difficult on a configuration level.
- you should use a simplier and common approach - move the desired IPs into some VLAN, assign them a separate prefix (of course) and then route this prefix as you like: either assign to to the policy, or just make it use another FIB/routing table, or whatever - everything will be easier.

Yup, assigning these IP to a separate policy is doable, but this is exactly when I meant saying *overcomplicated*.